# Возможно ли определить с какой версии установлено приложение не считая обновлений?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Возможно ли определить с какой версии установлено приложение не считая обновления? Либо просто определить что пользователь установил приложение из play маркета вручную, либо ему пришло обновление?

Answer (score 2):

1. Первичную версию можно определить только заранее записав её при первом запуске приложения в `SharedPreference` (удалятся при очистке данных/кэша приложения) или в отдельный файл в неприватную папку приложения (юзер может сам вручную удалить сей файл) и считать потом это значение оттуда.
2. Определить сам юзер обновился или автоматом невозможно.